# displaying metrialize css buttons side by side

Tags: html, css, materialize

I have the following layout for the image cards using materialize css:
[image]

as you can see my buttons are one above the other, here is my html:

```
 <div class="col m4 14">
                <div class="card hoverable">
                    <div class="card-image">
                        <a href="/uploads/{{imageName}}" data-lightbox="mygallery" data-title="This is a test">
                            <img class="materialboxed" src="/uploads/{{imageName}}" width="250">
                        </a>
                    </div>

                    <div class="card-action2">
                        <form action="/user/{{id}}?_method=DELETE" method="POST">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn-floating btn waves-effect waves-light red">
                                <i class="material-icons">delete</i>
                            </button>
                        </form>
                        <form action="/user/{{id}}?_method=DELETE" method="POST">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn-floating btn waves-effect waves-light blue">
                                <i class="material-icons">edit</i>
                            </button>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

I am using the standard materialize css and not made any changes to the materialize.css file. How can I have both the buttons in the same line and side by side, pulled to the bottom right of the image.

I also want to scale the images to the same size, as you can see when the images are not the same size the cards are also of different sizes.

Thanks in advance guys.

Comment: first of all there is a problem in first line. change `"col m4 14"` to `"col m4 l4"`

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. changed to l4 now

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Materialize grid system](https://materializecss.com/grid.html) to do this and position your elements as you want. for example if you put buttons in two `col s6` classes, their position will be side by side.

change your code to this :

```
<div class="col m4 l4">
            <div class="card hoverable">
            <div class="row">
                  <div class="col s12">
                  <div class="card-image">
                    <a href="/uploads/{{imageName}}" data-lightbox="mygallery" data-title="This is a test">
                        <img class="materialboxed" src="/uploads/{{imageName}}" width="250">
                    </a>
                </div>
                  </div>
            </div>


                <div class="card-action2">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col s6">
                    <form action="/user/{{id}}?_method=DELETE" method="POST">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn-floating btn waves-effect waves-light red">
                            <i class="material-icons">delete</i>
                        </button>
                    </form>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col s6">
                    <form action="/user/{{id}}?_method=DELETE" method="POST">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn-floating btn waves-effect waves-light blue">
                            <i class="material-icons">edit</i>
                        </button>
                    </form>
                  </div>
                </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bahmanparsamanesh/cL9p2w1o/)

Answer (score 0):

You should use `style="display: inline;"` because Forms are Block Level Elements.

```
                    <form style="display:inline;" action="/user/{{id}}?_method=DELETE" method="POST">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn-floating btn waves-effect waves-light red">
                            <i class="material-icons">delete</i>
                        </button>
                    </form>
                    <form style="display: inline;" action="/user/{{id}}?_method=DELETE" method="POST">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn-floating btn waves-effect waves-light blue">
                            <i class="material-icons">edit</i>
                        </button>
                    </form>
```

Comment: Thanks Badgy, that solved my first problem :-) can you also help me regarding displaying the cards in the same size no matter what the actual image size is?

Comment: @AminBaig You could try to give each of the Cards a fixed width and height, im not home so i cant test anything out Right now… :/

Comment: I tried that but it stretches the images. I have seen image galleries which fill the card with the image without stretching them but can't find example code on how to do that.

Comment: @AminBaig Images Always have a Set Resolution and Ratio, you cant put any Picture in the same Frame without making it stretched, in my one App i simply tried to get Images with a nearly equal Aspect Ratio and then limited the size of the Card.

Comment: I also solved aligning the buttons to the right by giving the card action 2 block a right-align

Comment: @AminBaig Okay, i think Materialize also has a simple "Right" class for those aligns, they have good docs.